# How to know what index is being used in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, indexing

Having multiple indices for an SQL table, is there a way to know what index will be used automatically when using a specific query?

EDIT: I wanted the question to be general, but I mostly use MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite

Comment: On most RDBMS, use `explain plan` to see how the query is being parsed and what indexes are being used.

Comment: Keep in mind that just because an index exists, doesn't mean the optimizer will decide to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the EXPLAIN PLAN statement to see what the dbms will do with your query.